# Problema al leer CSV Php

Tags: php, csv

Tengo un fichero CSV con el siguiente formato:

```
Organizacion;descripcion;tipo,ubicacion
<Organization>;<descripcion>;<#tipo>;campo
<Organization>_social;<descripcion>;<#tipo>;ciudad
<Organization>;<descripcion>;<#tipo>;ciudad
<Organization>;<descripcion>;<#tipo>;mar
Miempresa;Esta es mi empresa;Pyme;ciudad
......
```

Siendo la primera linea la cabecera.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
    $file = "mifile.csv";
    $fp = fopen($file, "r");

    while(!feof($fp)){
        // Leyendo una linea
        $traer = fgets($fp);
        // Imprimiendo una linea
        echo nl2br($traer);
    }
```

El resultado al imprimir las líneas es el siguiente:

```
Organizacion;descripcion;tipo,ubicacion
;;<#tipo>;campo 
_social;;<#tipo>;ciudad
;;<#tipo>;ciudad 
;;<#tipo>;mar
Miempresa;Esta es mi empresa;Pyme;ciudad
```

Es decir, no recoge los campos que están entre "<" y ">" excepto el que tiene "<#..>".

Necesito comprobar que el fichero contiene los valores "" y "" en cada línea, ya que el CSV es una plantilla que en otra función reemplaza sustituye esos valores por los introducidos por el usuario para generar otro CSV

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que estas imprimiendo sobre HTML, el cual es un lenguaje de etiquetas `<algo>`, por lo tanto el navegador lo toma como elemento y no como texto.

Puedes usar [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.htmlentities.php) para convertir el texto en [HTML Entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) y que de esta manera se impriman

```
$file = "mifile.csv";
$fp = fopen($file, "r");

while(!feof($fp)){
    // Leyendo una linea
    $traer = fgets($fp);
    // Imprimiendo una linea
    echo nl2br(htmlentities($traer));
}
```